# /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.9' not found error while installing Qt5 on Linux

Tags: linux, qt, qt5

I am trying to install Qt5 on Linux but I get this errors:

```
[root@localhost Desktop]# ./qt-linux-opensource-1.4.0-x86-online.run
./qt-linux-opensource-1.4.0-x86-online.run: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by ./qt-linux-opensource-1.4.0-x86-online.run)
./qt-linux-opensource-1.4.0-x86-online.run: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.9' not foundc (required by ./qt-linux-opensource-1.4.0-x86-online.run)
./qt-linux-opensource-1.4.0-x86-online.run: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.10' not found (required by ./qt-linux-opensource-1.4.0-x86-online.run)
./qt-linux-opensource-1.4.0-x86-online.run: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.11' not found (required by ./qt-linux-opensource-1.4.0-x86-online.run)
./qt-linux-opensource-1.4.0-x86-online.run: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by ./qt-linux-opensource-1.4.0-x86-online.run)
```

I installed this file http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/gcc/SLE-10_SDK/i586/libstdc++44-4.4.2_20100116-28.1.i586.rpm and `/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found` error gone. But how can I fix others?

Comment: What distribution are you trying to install it on? RHEL5? RHEL6? Fedora 19?

Comment: @Slavik81 I use fedora 7.

Answer (score 2):

Your operating system is not officially supported. Given that, I think trying to use a pre-built binary is a fool's errand. Your best bet is building Qt 5 from source... and even then your system libraries might be too old.

I know it's possible to build Qt5 on RHEL6, and I know it's pretty much impossible on RHEL5. RHEL5 is based on Fedora 6, and RHEL6 is based on Fedora 12/13.

Fedora 7 falls in between the two, but is definitely closer to the wrong end of the scale. The primary question is what version of gstreamer you have. [To build Qt Multimedia, you require gstreamer >=0.10.24](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git). If you have that, you have at least some chance of making it work.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mess with the system libraries -- just upgrade your distribution. [Glibc 2.11 has been released in 2009](http://www.sourceware.org/ml/libc-announce/2010/msg00000.html), that's **four years** ago.

Comment: I can not upgrade my distro. Is there any way to install Glibc 2.11 to my fedora 7. Any rpm?

Comment: Then try compiling Qt from sources. Again, Fedora 7 is from 2008, that's **five** years ago. Now we're at Fedora 17!

Comment: I get error while I am compiling Qt5. Can yo look this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17566762/ssl-qsslsocket-openssl-cpp1414-error-q-ssl-ctrl-was-not-declared-in-this-scop