# ssl/qsslsocket_openssl.cpp:1414: error: q_ssl_ctrl was not declared in this scope error

Tags: linux, qt, compilation, qt5

I am trying to compile Qt5. I download Qt 5.1 from here: [download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.1/5.1.0/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.1.0.tar.gz](http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.1/5.1.0/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.1.0.tar.gz). But after "make" command I get this error: 
`ssl/qsslsocket_openssl.cpp:1414: error: q_ssl_ctrl was not decleared in this scope` 
I can not find anything on Google. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

configure qt with builtin ssl or compile openssl yourself and add it to your libraries in configure. I attach a expample configure line (was for qt4.8 static commercial installer on msvc2008!)

```
configure -static -commercial -release -no-fast -qt-sql-sqlite -qt-sql-mysql -qt-zlib -mmx -3dnow -sse -sse2 -openssl-linked -script -scripttools -no-declarative -arch windows -no-style-cde -no-style-motif -no-style-cleanlooks -no-style-plastique -no-webkit -nomake examples -nomake demos -no-qt3support -no-phonon -no-multimedia -no-dbus -no-opengl -no-xmlpatterns -platform win32-msvc2008 -I mysql\include -L mysql\lib -l mysqlclient -l libmysql
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Sebastian Lange. I compiled openssl but how can I add it to my libraries?

Comment: Try using the ``-L path/to/ssllib`` for the directory having the library and ``-l libssl`` for the library name in your configure command. The QT Docs/forums have a number of guides if you still encounter problems.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have the development files of openssl v1.0.0 or greater installed.
or use qt internal version as described by Sebastian